# Data type not found in Data Extension creation

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions, attribute

in a DE including products details, I have an attribute which include the url of the image of product.
I should choose the data type url (as it is in the related synchronized DE) but I can't find . 
I have put text but I wonder if I'll have issue with the AMPscript as I'll have to display the product image in the order confirmation email.

Thank you so much, 
G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_data_extension_data_types.htm&type=5) are the available data types for data extension fields:

- Text
- Number
- Date
- Boolean
- EmailAddress
- Phone
- Decimal

For an image url, a text data type will work. Just be sure to make your field length large enough to accommodate all of your url's.